# insert row text into variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

```
NSString *stalklabel = ;

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://news.search.yahoo.com/rss?ei=UTF-8&p=%@&fr=news-us-ss", stalklabel];
```

I have the code above, and I need to know how to get the value of the row that the user pressed into `stalklabel`. I use Core Data to fill the table; does that complicate things?

EDIT:

Sorry; to clarify:

I have this in view1:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [[self appDelegate] setCurrentlySelectedBlogItem:[[[self rssParser]rssItems]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    //[self.appDelegate loadNewsDetails];

    NewsDetailViewController *newsDetail = [[NewsDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewsDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    //NSManagedObject *selectedObject = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    // ...
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    //newsDetail.titleTextView.text = [[[self appDelegate] currentlySelectedBlogItem]title];
    //newsDetail.descriptionTextView.text = [[[self appDelegate] currentlySelectedBlogItem]description];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:newsDetail animated:YES];
    [newsDetail release];   
}
```

so when the user presses the row and gets sent to view2, view2 uses another class to fill the view. My original code with the URL resides in the other class. So I need to transfer the row text value to a variable in the other class and insert it into the URL so I can fill view2 with relevant data; does that make sense?

Comment: hmm, seems as if Jacob and I totally understood ur question differently. can u clarify, if u need to know about NSString operations or the mapping of UITableViewCells and the data they represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a cell gets selected, it tabelView will call its delegate method [`tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3adidSelectRowAtIndexPath%3a)

You get the indexPath. If you use a `fetchedResultsController` (and you should with CoreData), you can simply do

```
YourClass *object = (YourClass *)[[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *aString = object.text;
```

See the [CoreDataBooks example code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreDataBooks/Introduction/Intro.html)

**edit**
Regarding your code you seem to have a "Super-AppDelegate". That is not needed.

Your NewsDetailViewController should have a property to point on the object. like `news`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    NewsDetailViewController *newsDetail = [[NewsDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewsDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    NSManagedObject *selectedObject = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    newsDetail.news = selectedObject;  
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:newsDetail animated:YES];
    [newsDetail release];    
}
```

In the `-viewDidLoad:` of your NewsDetailViewController you can setup your view with the data from your news object.

Comment: RssFunViewController *object = (RssFunViewController *)[[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *aString = object.text;
rssParser.stalklabel.text = aString;

Comment: Any reason why the above wouldnt work? rssParser is a pointer to the class with URL stuff in it

Comment: From the name RssFunViewController I would suggest, that it is not a NSManagedObject or one descent of it. NSManagedObject *selectedObject = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]; looks ok

Comment: thanks for that, RssFunViewController is the class that i'm working in. I replaced that line with your edited line and i'm getting quite a few of these errors: "request for member 'text' in something not a structure or union"

Answer (score 1):

Use `stringWithFormat:`

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://news.search.yahoo.com/rss?ei=UTF-8&p=%@&fr=news-us-ss", stalklabel]];
```

Comment: `stringWithFormat:` does not need the `nil` sentinel. :)

Comment: @Dave, true. I'm so used to using it that I stuck it in there anyway. :-)