# iPhone Core Data problems

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 NSManagedObject *selectedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
 BlogRssParser *blogRss = [[BlogRssParser alloc] init];
 [blogRss setSelectedObject:selectedObject];

 RssFunViewController *rssFun = [[RssFunViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RssFunViewController" bundle:nil];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:rssFun animated:YES];
 [rssFun release];

}
```

This is my code so when the user taps the row, its supposed to take the value from the row and insert it into here:

```
NSString *terms = [[[self selectedObject] valueForKey:@"data"]description];
NSLog(@"%@", terms);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://news.search.yahoo.com/rss?ei=UTF-8&p=%@&fr=news-us-ss", terms]];
```

But "terms" is showing up as (null) in the log? Not the value of the clicked row

Comment: Please explain what the top bit of code does. I think it slightly difficult to read a question that starts with code.

Comment: I do try and accept answers but sometimes the answer just didnt come through. The top bit of the code should get the current value of the row in the table (which is filled via Core Data) then in another class i declare a NSManagedObject property called selectedObject and set "terms" to this Object. Which i then want to put into the URL below it to return RSS feeds

Comment: Are the objects possibly sitting in different contexts? Are you sure you're setting the terms on the *same* object?

Comment: You could be right. How would i find that out. Can i do anything more than declaring a property in the class with the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see, that u used some codes, [I posted here for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147461/insert-row-text-into-variable). But you shouldnt just copy and paste it.
In my code `selectedObject` is not a member, as it is absolutely not necessary.

This line

```
 NSManagedObject *selectedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

points to a non-member variable
while

```
[self selectedObject]
```

points to a member — a totally different thing.

**edit**
Is the second part in the TableViewContoller or in the DetailedView?

Comment: In blogrssparser.m that's where the code is kept to fill rssfunviewcontrollers tableview, so what is your advice for the problem above? Thanks

Comment: No, one in RootViewController (top one) where i want the user to click a row, then the 2nd code is in BlogRssParser.m where the URL logic is.

Comment: In that case the problems shouldn't be in the code u posted. U should post everything that is related to CoreData, as i think, ur fetchedResult seems to be nil'd out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172108/iphone-passing-value-to-other-class this is another post of mine, this outlines, with code, what problem i'm facing!